# Tcl: What's the fastest way to check a blank string

Tags: tcl

What's the fastest way to check a blank string?

- `[string eq $s ""]`
- `[string compare $s ""]`
- `[expr $s == ""]`
- `[regexp ^$ $s]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect that either:

```
string equal $s ""
```

or

```
expr {$s eq ""}
```

would be fastest; the two cases will generate virtually identical bytecode so I wouldn't expect to distinguish them.

Answer (score 2):

```
proc check {} {
set s {}
puts "string equal   ->[time {string eq $s ""} 100000]"
puts "string compare ->[time {string compare $s ""} 100000]"
puts "regexp         ->[time {regexp ^$ $s} 100000]"
puts "expr ==        ->[time {expr {$s == ""}} 100000]"
puts "expr eq        ->[time {expr {$s eq ""}} 100000]"
}
check ; # See the behavior in your PC
```

Comment: I wonder if that's a good way to do it. The first method of testing always take the longest time (i.e. the method that takes the longest no more takes the longest if it's not at the top anymore). Personally though, I think string equal and compare are the faster ones. Though when writing in `if`, I'd use `$s eq ""`. [See this wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/15322).

Comment: That method runs the real risk of not comparing exactly like with like.